# Use ucwords function to $_POST values as an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

i have this array:

```
Array
(
    [name] => jim ross
    [address] => colorado
    [occupation] => actor
)
```

i will use the following code to get the data from the form

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $values = $_POST['details'];
}
```

here $values contains the name, address and occupation

Now I want to insert it into database by capitalizing each words, but `ucwords()` doesn't apply to arrays. How can I apply it to every element in my array?

Comment: Please do some research... hint: function ends with 'first'

Comment: after some research i ended up to this site .......

Comment: `ucwords(strtolower($values));`

Comment: @Jack actually i want to use ucwords() function .... but it does not applies to an array ....... and my data are in array ..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply a function to every element in your array, you can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map)

```
$values = array_map('ucwords', $_POST['details']);
// each element in $values has had ucwords() applied to it
```

Comment: thanks buddy for understanding what i wanted to do :D

Comment: @rt8s You should not be using `mysql_` functions any more, but it can be applied in the same manner.

Comment: as i am new to php would you please tell me why i should not use mysql_ functions any more........i have been taught to do so :(

Comment: @rt8s See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for more answers.